# How connect to localhost mysql base from docker in spring application

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker

I try connecting spring boot application in docker with MySQL base on localhost

It's my application.properties, but the application cannot find the base

```
server.port = 8080


spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/TestDB?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=false
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
```

I think the IP for MySQL in the container is different from the IP on the localhost

How I can connect to MySQL on localhost?

Comment: Use `host.docker.internal` inspite of `localhost`.

Comment: @Amitkumar MYSQL_HOST:host.docker.internal that's right?

Comment: have you tried telnet the containers from your host laptop / computer and is it reachable ?

Comment: I would recommend going over : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach to get clarity for your use case.